# Connecting Matrox TripleHead2Go Digital Edition via HDMI

Tags: vga

My laptop has a VGA and an HDMI output, and I have the [TripleHead2Go Digital](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/digital/) edition. It came with a VGA/VGA connection cable and a DVI/DVI connection cable.

Right now I have three 24" monitors that I want to run at 1920x1080 each.

When I'm connected via VGA, the max resolution per screen is only 1280x1024.

Since my laptop has only HDMI, I've tried using an HDMI to DVI adapter, but either only one screen is picked up at 1920x1080, or the entire deal doesn't work and my computer flashes between the normal desktop screen and black.

Is there something that I need to adjust on my computer first to get this HDMI/DVI connection to work?  Or, can I obtain a VGA/DVI adapter to see if that could work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Matrox the [TripleHead2Go Digital](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/digital/) (the one with VGA input) has a maximum output of

- 4080x768    (**3** x 1360x768)
- 3840x1080 (**2** x 1920x1080)

Not 3x 1920x1080.

The [TripleHead2Go Digital **SE**](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/digital_se/) (displayport input) allows you up to 5760x1080 (3x 1920x1080@50Hz), but then you would need an active HDMI to displayport convertor.

And that assume that your laptop can generate the needed resolution.
Can you add the model of the laptop to the post?

Comment: Asus G74SX-DH71 is the laptop model.

Comment: I suppose using a vga to dvi adapter and connecting the dvi cable from the computer to the unit can't "trick" the unit into thinking it's getting a signal from a dvi from my computer?

Comment: The graphical 'card' on your http://www.asus.com/ROG/G74SX/ is a Nvidia Geforce GTX 560M. That should be more than modern enough to generate the output for 5760x1080 though the analog output needs a DAC to turn that into ancient VGA signal.  A regular 400Mhz DAC tops out near 400MHz, which is allows 2560x1920@63 Hz. Which is a logn winded way of saying that the hardware should allow those resolutions. Even when using VGA – However turning VGA into DVI is not merely a matter of a plug, unless turn needs analog DVI. And then VGA would also have sufficed.

Comment: Which means that however you turn it you will need either:
1) A relative expensive active convertor. (VGA → DVI or HDMI to DVI)
2) Or feed two displays off the Matrox (via VGA) and one of HDMI. HDMI to DVI is easy and cheap)
3) Or you need another graphical card. Somehow. E.g using en external GPU. Works. More powerful then any notebook solution. And not portable.
(also see 
http://forum.notebookreview.com/e-gpu-external-graphics-discussion/418851-diy-egpu-experiences.html#introduction )

Comment: I will try option 2, for I have HDMI to HDMI availability between the computer and monitor.  I just hope that the computer will be able to pick up all that fun.

Down the road I guess I should invest in an desktop with multiple GPU's shouldn't I?  I daytrade at the moment and can look to set aside something.

Thanks Hennes, you were extremely helpful!!!

Comment: Turns out option 2 won't work.  Even the matrox unit won't properly display 1920x1080 on each of the 2 monitors!  And the one connected via HDMI doesn't even register.

I think I'll probably look into a desktop over the next few months :)

Comment: A desktop will solve most of those problems since it allows you to use a 'normal' full size graphical card. Just make sure you get one which can drive 3 monitors at the same time. (Not sure about nvidia cards, but I am familiar with AMD/AT and those often come in a flavour with 4 ports to connect monitor to, but to use more then 2 monitors one of them needs to use display port. Not all of them, but most. So buyer beware.

Comment: Would be interesting to know if anyone ever tried with an active HDMI to DisplayPort converter and got this to work.